# WordPress, CiviCRM and CloudFlare

Tags: wordpress, core

Please forgive me as I'm new to CiviCRM and I'm just starting to get my head around how it works.

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience using the above combination? What rules in Cloudflare (If any) did you need to put in place, and did you need to make any custom changes to WordPress in order to get things to work properly?

Comment: Are you getting any issue?  - I have worked with Wordpress + CiviCRM + cloudFlare - it works perfectly - cloudFlare adds as an additional security + performs - If you have any more question feel free to ask - I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - I found that I needed to add a few different page rules in for ours to work - that's what I'm questioning about everyone else.

Some of our page rules exclude caching on https://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM* as an example, but I'm not sure if I need it

Comment: CloudFlare does cache page - I don't think you can cache all the pages because some need to pick dynamic values from the database - I could say set up the default setting for now and when you start using it you will understand - Thanks

Comment: I'm encountering an issue with CloudFlare presenting a CAPTCHA to calls to the the REST API.

We have a sign-up form on another WP-Engine site that uses Gravity Forms Webhook to post the sign-up to Civi.

I've tried adding a Page Rule in CF which sets the "Security Level" to "Essentially Off", but still getting the CAPTCHA.

I'm groping through the CloudFlare support articles. I think my next trial is to see if it is different to create a WAF "skip" rule. But if anyone else has been down this road... please halp